# Необходимо достать информацию из нескольких файлов csv и добавить её в отдельный файл

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

Сразу скажу, что являюсь новичком в python.
Суть программы в том, что мы берём 2 файла csv, и затем информацию оттуда передаём в третий файл.
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv


from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

def open_file1 ():

    file1 = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('Python Files', '*.csv')])
    fixed_df = pd.read_csv(file1, encoding = 'latin_1')
    file2 = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('Python Files', '*.csv')])
    fixed_df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, encoding = 'latin_1')
    print(fixed_df [:3])
    print(fixed_df2 [:3])

    with open(fixed_df, 'r') as score, open(fixed_df2, 'r') as input, open('result.csv', 'a+') as result:
        score_reader = csv.reader(score)
        marklist_reader = csv.reader(input)
        result = csv.writer(result)
        result.writerows((marklist_reader, score_reader))

    plt.show()

window = Tk()

lbl = Label(window, text="Загрузите файлы!")
lbl.grid(column=3, row=3)

btn = Button(window, text="Загрузите файлы по очереди!", command=lambda: open_file1())
btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

window.geometry('400x250')
window.title("Hi")
window.mainloop()
```

После выбора файлов, выдаёт ошибку:

**with open(fixed_df, 'r') as score, open(fixed_df2, 'r') as input, open('result.csv', 'a+') as result:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame***

Я не знаю уже что делать, поэтому решился спросить у знающих людей. По идее, всё должно работать нормально. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: open первым параметром принимает путь к файлу, а вы туда передаете датафреймы

Comment: Ранее менял первые параметры open на file1 и file2, остаётся та же проблема. Так же пытался сделать, передав open первым параметром askopenfile с выбором пути

Comment: askopenfile сразу открывает файл, а вам нужно имя файла. Используйте askopenfilename.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, ошибку понял!